# Jasmine TypeScript test Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write some Angular Controller tests for my App in Type Script for couple of days and without any success. Before i start i would like to mention that this is the first time that i'm writting test i jasmine. My problem is that i can't mock dependent service in order to test controller. Any help or point to right direction would be good.

Angular Module :

```
 angular.module('some.module', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCookies', 'smart-table']);
```

Angular Controller :

```
module App.Controllers {

export class TestController{
    static $inject = ["$scope","SomeService"];
    WhatController: () => string;
    constructor(private $scope: App.IAppScope, private SomeService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.WhatController = function (): string {
            return SomeService.someAction();
        };
    }
}

angular.module("some.module").controller("TestController", TestController);
```

}

Angular Service :

```
module App.Services {

export class SomeService{
    httpService: ng.IHttpService;
    static $inject = ["$http"];
    someAction: () => any;

    constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
        var service = this;
        service.someAction= () => {
           return "test";
        }
    }
}

factory.$inject = ['$http'];
function factory($http: ng.IHttpService) {
    return new SomeService($http);
}

angular.module('some.module').factory('SomeService', factory);
```

}

Karma File :

```
    module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: 'Scripts',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'jasmine-matchers'],
        files: [

            { pattern: 'angular.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-mocks.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-ui-router.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-animate.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-translate.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-translate-loader-url.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'angular-cookies.js', included: true },
            { pattern: 'smart-table.js', included: true },

            '../app/app.module.js',
            '../app/pages/**/*.controller.js',

            //Here are controller files
            { pattern: '../app/pages/**/*.spec.js', included: true },

        ],
        exclude: ['**/*min.js'],
        preprocessors: {
            '../app/pages/**/*.controller.js': ['coverage'],
        },

        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,

        coverageReporter: {
        type : 'html',
        dir : 'coverage/'
    }
    })
}
```

Test :

```
    'use strict';
describe("complaints.controller.test", () => {
    var $http: ng.IHttpService;
    var mockSomeServices: App.Services.SomeServices;
    var mock = angular.mock;


    beforeEach(() => {
        mock.module('ui.router');
        mock.module('ngAnimate');
        mock.module('ui.bootstrap');
        mock.module('pascalprecht.translate');
        mock.module('ngCookies');
        mock.module('smart-table');
      });

    //This don't work mockSomeServices  is undefined
    beforeEach(mock.inject((_$http_, $injector) => {
        $http = _$http_;
        mockSomeServices = $injector.get('SomeServices');
    }));

   //This also don't work mockSomeServices  is undefined
    beforeEach(mock.inject((_$http_, $injector, SomeServices) => {
        $http = _$http_;
        mockSomeServices = SomeServices;
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mock a service, you do so like this:

```
angular.mock.module(($provide: ng.auto.IProvideService): void => {
    $provide.constant("SomeService", SomeService = { });
});
```

In your controller, I don't think you want to mock your service. You want to know that it was called and you can do that by putting a spy on your service.

```
spyOn(SomeService, "someAction");
```

If you want it to return some data to use/validate in the controller, you can do:

```
spyOn(SomeService, "someAction").and.returnValue(/* data */);
```

Then you assert that it was called and that the data is what you expected:

```
expect(SomeService.someAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(yourController.someValue).toEqual("someValue");
```